# EF DBFirst, table gets removed from model

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, ef-database-first

Something strange is happening in my EF Database-first EDMX model.
I wanted to update the model after making some changes in the DB.
The update operation removed a table that did not received any changes. That table was present in the model for a long time and never had any problems.

Obviously, I'm getting the Error 11007 : Entity type 'MyTable' is not mapped.

I tried several things:

- Close the EDMX without saving, retry: same problem.
- Redo "Update Model from DB", check the box in front of the removed table... But it is not getting added to the model (?)
- Close Visual Studio, retry: same problem.
- Try in another EDMX (I have 5-6 models in the solution, all linked to the same (big) DB) : There the table is not removed (!)
- Rename the table in the DB : With the new name, it IS added.
- Clean the EDMX's XML from everything that is linked to that table, retry the update: no effect.

What could be causing a particular table to not be added in a particular emdx model file? This *seems* like a bug to me.

NB. Before the table is removed, it is listed in the "Refresh" tab of the "Update from DB" Wizard.

VS 2017 15.4.2 (last update done the day before the problem appeared...?)

EDIT - More information :
The Table is named "DocumentStatuses" and formed of two columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [cov].[DocumentStatuses](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Label] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The DocumentStatus entity maps the Id column to an enum. It worked fine until this problem appeared (but it continues to work fine for 2 other entity data models).

### EDIT 2

I'm going crazy with this bug. It suddenly appeared, in the same edmx, for 5 others tables that are not linked to each other.
I tried to create another EDMX, with another name, and it has the same bug.
I tried to add tables one-by-one, and suddenly, the problems appears. No matter which table I add, the 5 others that were present in the model simply disappear and I get the Error 11007.

If anyone has the tiniest idea, it is really welcome.

### EDIT 3

I created a new solution, added my tables to a new entity data model... and the problems remains. EF REFUSES to map the tables.
**Are there some logs that VS creates when we do "Update from database"?**.

Next step I'll try is to create a VM and try in it.

Comment: After beeing removed, the table is again listed in the "Add" tab, but it doesn't get added and stays in this tab. Reaaally weird.

Comment: You should try to give us something by which we can reproduce the problem, although that's probably pretty hard. Or at least give some details of the defiant table.

Comment: I cannot myself reproduce the problem in another EDMX in the same solution and generated from the same DB... The table is a really simple table: Id int, Label varchar(50) with no auto-increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created "separator" tables with names formed with 20 underscores. Like this : schema._________________________

So I had "separators" between my schemas in SSMS. These dummy tables were not mapped of course.
I removed them and... the problem disappeared !
This ***is*** a bug and I reported it:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/418

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" the problem by renaming the table in the database.
This is only a workaround but it's all I could come up with.